# Probability - sum from consecutive trials (with restrictions)

Tags: probability

I came up with this problem when commuting and can not find a simple solution to it. Does it even have a mathematical solution?

Assume that a train starts from point A and travels to point B. There are a total of 11 stations, which means that when the train stops at point B it has stopped a total of 10 times.

This particular train is somewhat old and acts up a lot. Because of this the journey between two adjacent stations can be expected to take either 5 minutes more than scheduled (50% probability) or 5 minutes less than scheduled (50% probability).

Question: What is the probability that the train arrives on time (or early) to its final destination? What is the average delay?

**Assumptions:**

- Passengers entering and exiting the train takes 0 time
- There are no time bufferts, the train is scheduled to leave a station as soon as it is arriving according to the time table.

**Notes:**

- A train can never leave a station before its scheduled departure.
- Results from 10 000 000 trials in python suggests that about 75.39% of trains are delayed and the average delay is approximately 9.80 minutes.

Comment: Then does a train arrive on time only if not delayed at any station?

Comment: @BruceET I don't think so. If the train has delay at station1 then this can be straightened again on the traject station1-station2.

Comment: @drhab is correct -  time lost can be recovered, but the train will never have a time buffer saved up. Pretty much like in the real world =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d_{i,j}$ be the probability that the train is delayed $5\times(j-1)$ minutes after $i$ legs of the journey. Then we can write the vector $$d_i=\begin{bmatrix}d_{i,1}\\d_{i,2}\\...\\d_{i,10}\\\end{bmatrix}$$

When the train has traveled zero legs of its journey, it not delayed with probability 1, so $$d_0=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\...\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we need the transition matrix. If the train is not delayed after the $k$th leg, the probability that it will not be delayed after $k+1$ legs is .5, and the probability that it will be delayed 5 minutes is .5, so the first column of the transition matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}.5\\.5\\0\\...\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

If instead the train is 5 minutes late after $k$ legs, then after $k+1$ legs it will be on time with probability .5, and 10 minutes late with probability .5, so the second column of the transition matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}.5\\0\\.5\\0\\0\\...\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Continuing this analysis, the transition matrix for the first 10 legs is $$P=\begin{bmatrix}.5&.5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\.5&0&.5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&.5&0&.5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&.5&0&.5&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&.5&0&.5\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&.5&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Now $d_i$ can be written as $$d_i=Pd_{i-1}$$ so $$d_{10}=P^{10}d_0\approx\begin{bmatrix}.24609\\.20508\\.20508\\.11719\\.11719\\.043945\\.043945\\.0097656\\.0097656\\.00097656\\.00097656\\\end{bmatrix}$$

As your simulation predicted, 75.39(1) percent of trains are delayed at the last station.

Expected minutes of delay at the final station is $$\sum_{j=1}^{11}5\times(j-1)\times d_{10,j}=10.42$$